# How to pragmatically schedule Celery task with dynamic inputs?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have this situation where I need to pragmatically schedule a task, and the task definition requires certain input parameters each time it needs to be executed. Consider the following task function:

```
@task
def add_numbers(a, b):
   sum = a + b
   return sum
```

Now if I need to run the above task at two different time instances with different input parameters ex T1->add_numbers(4,5) and T2->add_numbers(2,2), how do I go about it. Thanks for the help.

ENV: Django 1.4, Celery 3.0

Comment: Hello Mr. Khan, 

We are also try to distribute and schedule our jobs using celery. We have a requirement to schedule or re-schedule tasks at the runtime. This requirement seems very similar to the one you mentioned in your questions.

I just wanted to check where you able to get this resolved.

Thanks,
Hussain Bohra

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem too, and I think there is another way to help you out.
the answer of @narced133 works only if the varies of params are limited, then what if we have thousands kinds of params?

solution:
refactor your `celery task` to accept a function as param, and the function will generate or get the params that are the real params for your `celery task`: `add_numbers`.

Answer (score 1):

See the Celery documentation on periodic tasks for an example of how to call a task with arguments at a specified interval. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries

In your example, you could use something like:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'T1': {
        'task': 'tasks.add_numbers',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=1),,
        'args': (4, 5)
    },
    'T2': {
        'task': 'tasks.add_numbers',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=16, minute=0),,
        'args': (2, 2)
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks @narced133 for the direction. Will it a try and update.